# \em of ulem package surrounding by environment does not compile

Tags: emphasis, ulem

The following code does not compile if any `%` is removed. It reports *run away argument*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center} %\em
        This is center
    \end{center}
    \begin{quote} %\em
        This is quote
    \end{quote}
    \begin{itemize} %\em
        \item This is itemize
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{tabular}{c} %\em
        This is tabular
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My question is whether it is possible to fix it so that `\em` of `ulem` (as an underlining `\em`) works everywhere `\em` of LaTeX works.

Comment: `\em` with `ulem` wants to be terminated by `}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\em` with `ulem` becomes

```
\def\@tempa{\uline}%
\global\let\UL@ender\UL@swender
\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\ifnum\z@=\string`}\fi
```

This is an interesting trick for essentially turning

```
{\em something}
```

into

```
\uline{something}
```

A consequence of this is that `\em` *needs* to see an explicit closing brace and cannot be “free”.

Underlining cannot be done like a font change that respects any grouping mechanism, so the answer to your question is: no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks. So the next problem: why not make underlining a font feature so that we will have `\ulshape` and `\textul`? It is cheaper to draw a line than to tune, for example, the italic version, right?

Comment: @Symbol1 One would need a special underlined font for this. But underlining a whole paragraph is something a typographer would do only under physical threat.

Comment: You owe me a coffee and a new keyboard.  But I'm still chuckling.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry for your keyboard. `;-)`