# Odd and even itemize symbols

Tags: enumitem, fontawesome

I want to make a dialogue between two people with the "commenting icon" in front of every sentence. I somewhat got what I want by using enumitem and fontawesome packages.
[image]

Here is my code so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[\color{blue!70!white}\faCommenting] First person
        \item[\color{green!70!black}\faCommentingO] Second person
        \item[\color{blue!70!white}\faCommenting] First person
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Now I'd like to define it as a new environment to use this multiple times. I know there is a \labelitemi command but it makes change for all items, for this I am not sure how to do it.

I did look up for old questions and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331978/how-to-conveniently-underline-even-or-odd-items-in-itemize?noredirect=1&lq=1) but couldn't understand the steps to have them fit my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `\newtoggle` command from `etoolbox`. To simplify the use of this solution, I defined a new itemize-like environment, `alternitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%
\newtoggle{greeny}
\newlist{alternitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[alternitem]{label={\iftoggle{greeny}%
{\color{green!70!black}\faCommentingO\global\togglefalse{greeny}}%
{\color{blue!70!white}\faCommenting\global\toggletrue{greeny}}%
}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{alternitem}
 \item First person
 \item Second person
 \item First person
 \item First person
 \item Second person
 \item First person
 \end{alternitem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice this \newtoggle :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can make a command that changes its own definition, and use that as the label, for example like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\makeatletter
  \def\speech@bubble@a{%
    \color{blue!70!white}\faCommenting
    \global\let\speech@bubble\speech@bubble@b
  }
  \def\speech@bubble@b{%
    \color{green!70!black}\faCommentingO
    \global\let\speech@bubble\speech@bubble@a
  }
  \newlist{dialog}{itemize}{1}
  \newlist{dialog*}{itemize}{1}
  \setlist[dialog]{
    before={\global\let\speech@bubble\speech@bubble@a},
    label={\speech@bubble},
  }
  \setlist[dialog*]{
    before={\global\let\speech@bubble\speech@bubble@b},
    label={\speech@bubble},
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First person first:
\begin{dialog}
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
\end{dialog}

Second person first:
\begin{dialog*}
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
  \item bla
\end{dialog*}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]